# rCharts installing problems

Tags: rcharts

I am using a windows 7 system and am trying to install rCharts. I keep getting the following error message:

Downloading github repo ramnathv/rCharts@master
Error in utils::unzip(src, list = TRUE) : 'exdir' does not exist

I am not very tech savvy and I need to use rCharts for a project. Any help in detail would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you install devtools?

Comment: Try to download the rCharts.zip [rCharts](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts)
and install it with `install_local(~/rCharts.zip)`